# Native Base Toast does not work in Live mode

Tags: react-native, react-redux, toast

We're using NativeBase in a React Native app. We're trying to show a Toast component based on an error that is set in a redux action because it happens via a call to the API.

It works perfectly in debug mode but does not work in Live build. Please, suggest what can we do?

Code:

```
export const toastr = {
  showToast: (message, duration = 2500) => {
    Toast.show({
      text: message,
      duration,
      position: 'bottom',
      textStyle: { textAlign: 'center' },
      buttonText: 'Okay',
    });
  },
};
```

And then

```
toastr.showToast('Verication code is invalid.');
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?